# Question on while (true), while (cin >> x && x), while (cin >> x, x)

Tags: c++, while-loop, comma-operator

I have encountered a problem with this task:

> your input is a number and the output is from 1 to the input number. If the number is zero, the output will be nothing.
>
> For instance your input is
>
> ```
> 5
> 10
> 3
> 0
> ```
>
> Your output will be
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> 1 2 3
> ```

So, there are apparently three answers.

The first solution uses this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int x;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> x;
    
        if (!x) break;
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i ++ ) cout << i << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The other two solutions replace this:

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> x;
    
    if (!x) break;
```

with this:

```
while (cin >> x && x)
```

or this:

```
while (cin >> x, x)
```

I understand the first solution, but not the other two.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What *do* you understand about them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/. It is not possible to "help you" because *we have no idea why you do not understand the code already*. Explaining things requires an actual point of confusion to be explained.

Comment: On;y the second one is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>>` operator, by convention, when applied to an `istream` object should return the `istream` object itself. So the return value of `cin >> x` is the `cin` object itself. When used as a Boolean, a stream object returns truthy if there are no errors in input/output.

```
while (cin >> x && x)
```

This says "while the loop successfully reads a value without errors *and* that value is not zero".

The comma operator is one of the more obscure pieces of C++ syntax. `a , b` evaluates `a` and then `b` and returns the result of `b`, discarding the result of `a` (this is assuming the comma doesn't do something else; for instance, in a function argument list the comma is part of that syntax, not its own operator). So `cin >> x, x` says "do the `cin` part, ignore the return value of that, and then check `x`".

```
while (cin >> x, x)
```

This says "get input and run as long as the input is nonzero". Crucially, errors in the input process are ignored here.

---

Minor note: Technically, programmers can overload the comma operator to call an arbitrary function. So if a programmer (whose mental health we might call into question) wrote a function like

```
void operator,(const istream& in, int x) {
  // Something really stupid ...
}
```

Then that function would get called by `cin >> x, x`. But every C++ style guide I've ever seen recommends against ever overloading the comma operator, so this is pathological at best.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the first program can invoke undefined behavior

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> x;

        if (!x) break;
        //...
```

The variable `x` is not initialized. So if the input

```
cin >> x;
```

is not successful because for example the user interrupted the input pressing the key combination `Ctrl + z` in Windows then in this if statement

```
if (!x) break;
```

there will be used the uninitialized variable that results in undefined behavior.

In this condition of the while loop

```
while (cin >> x, x)
```

there is used the comma operator. So whether the expression `cin >> x` was successful or not is ignored because the value of the expression is discarded.

You have to write

```
while (cin >> x && x != 0 )
```

Pay attention to that as the variable `x` has the signed type `int` then it means that the user can enter a negative value and the body of the loop will get the control. As a result a redundant new line character will be outputted

```
cout << endl;
```

So it is better to declare the variable `x` as having an unsigned integer type as for example

```
unsigned int x;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `while (cin >> x && x)` takes advantage of the fact than `cin` can be converted to `bool`. `(bool) cin` returns `true` if `cin` has no errors, which for most cases means always `true`.

The other one, I am not sure, because I am not familiar with that comma sintax.

Comment: the expression `a, b` evaluates from left to right, but discards the results except for the right most, `b` in this case. so `cin >> x, x` reads the value, and has `x` as the result. read more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) on the section "Built-in comma operator"

Answer (score 1):

First `while` can be read as:

- If `std::cin` has no errors after `cin >> x`, and `x != 0`, then execute the `while` block.
- Otherwise, exit the block.

Have a look at [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for streams, to understand how  `cin >> x` is used in a logical expression.

Second `while` can be read as:

- Do the `cin >> x`.
- Then, if `x != 0`, execute the `while` block.
- Otherwise, exit the block.

Have a look at [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other) for understanding the use of the `,` in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify rules for what input could be received. For example if you want positive integers only the you would specify `if x <= 0;` return error